# How to fix infinite re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.*

Found the answers to my question, but, nevertheless, I can’t understand how to fix this?

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM

function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [visible2, setVisible2] = useState(false);

  const arr1 = {
    company: [
      {
        id: "random1",
        companyName: "Apple"
      },
      {
        id: "random2",
        companyName: "Samsung"
      }
    ]
  };

  const onDataHandle = () => {
    return arr1.company.map(items => {
      return (
        <div>
          <span key={items.id}>
            {items.companyName}
            <span onClick={onHandleVisible}>Details</span>
          </span>
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  const onHandleVisible = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

  const onHandleVisible2 = () => {
    setVisible2(!visible2);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onHandleVisible2}>Show</button>
      {visible && onDataHandle()}
    </div>
  );
}

render (
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

I understand that this is due to the endless re-rendering, but what are the solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code logic (that is not entirely clear, I must say):

- <kbd>Show</kbd> button `onClick` triggeres `onHandleVisible2` callback which sets `visible2` state variable to `true`, but there's nothing in your code depending on that state variable, so nothing happens
- The block `{visible && onDataHandle()}` is supposed to trigger `onDataHandle()` (which never happens for above reason - `visible` stays equal to `false`), but `onDataHandle()` (even though attempts to return some JSX) will not add anything to render within `<App />` as it is not a ReactJS component
- (the minor one) if your intention with `onDatahandle()` was to return some component, wrapping up your span with extra `<div>` doesn't make much sense.

With all the above issues fixed, you would get something, like:

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM

function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [visible2, setVisible2] = useState(false);

  const arr1 = {
    company: [
      {
        id: "random1",
        companyName: "Apple"
      },
      {
        id: "random2",
        companyName: "Samsung"
      }
    ]
  };

  const Data = () => (
    <div>
      {
        arr1.company.map(items => (
          <span key={items.id}>
            {items.companyName}
            <span onClick={onHandleVisible}>Details</span>
            {visible && <span>There go {items.companyName} details</span>}
            <br />
          </span>))
       }
    </div>
  )

  const onHandleVisible = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

  const onHandleVisible2 = () => {
    setVisible2(!visible2);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onHandleVisible2}>Show</button>
      {visible2 && <Data />}
    </div>
  );
}

render (
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

**Note** one important issue stays unsolved in above code block: you used single variable (`visible`) for your entire app, so if you decide to control visibility of `details` for each item independently, you won't be able to do that with your current approach. But that's a totally different issue which you may post as a separate question.